# How to return new C++ objects in Cython?

Tags: c++, python, cython

I suspect there is an easy answer to this, but I need some help getting started with Cython. I have an existing C++ code base which I want to expose to Python via Cython. For each class I want to expose, I create a Cython cppclass `_ClassName` and the Python wrapper class `ClassName`.

A minmal example:

```
Object.h
CythonMinimal.pyx
setup.py
```

content of `Object.h`:

```
class Object {

public:

    Object clone() {
        Object o;
        return o; 
    }

};
```

content of `CythonMinimal.pyx`:

```
cdef extern from "Object.h":
    cdef cppclass _Object "Object":
        _Object() except +
        _Object clone()


cdef class Object:

    cdef _Object *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new _Object()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def clone(self):
        return self.thisptr.clone()
```

content of `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import os

os.environ["CC"] = "g++-4.7"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++-4.7"


modules = [Extension("CythonMinimal",
                     ["CythonMinimal.pyx"],
                     language = "c++",
                     extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
                     extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"])]

for e in modules:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature" : True}

setup(name="CythonMinimal",
     cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
     ext_modules=modules)
```

This is the error I get when compiling:

```
cls ~/workspace/CythonMinimal $ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
cythoning CythonMinimal.pyx to CythonMinimal.cpp

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def clone(self):
        return self.thisptr.clone()
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

    CythonMinimal.pyx:18:27: Cannot convert '_Object' to Python object
    building 'CythonMinimal' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3
    g++-4.7 -Wno-unused-result -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -c CythonMinimal.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/CythonMinimal.o -std=c++11
    cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    CythonMinimal.cpp:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
    error: command 'g++-4.7' failed with exit status 1
```

I assume that `_Object.clone` needs to return a `_Object` (cppclass type), but `Objet.clone` should return a `Object` (Python type). But how?

Comment: Could you possibly reduce this to a strictly minimal example (e.g. no more than one .h header file), and post here ALL files (C++ code, .h header, setup.py, cython wrapper, python application)? Since there exists no comprehensive documentation of the Cython/C++ binding, it would be helpful for many of us to collaborate here (or on cython-devel@python.org ?) to get one minimal example running.

Comment: I'll try to construct a minimal example. But am I wrong to think that this is a fairly general beginner's question and the solution should be obvious to someone with Cython+C++ experience?

Comment: There are not that many experienced Cython/C++ developers - and it is unlikely that they will become more numerous unless the documentation is improved. For me personally, learning Cython/C++ is high on my agenda; but after a first attempt ended with unsolved problems, I postponed further efforts. Therefore, I would like to try afresh with your example...

Comment: @JoachimWuttke I posted a complete minimal example. The problem remains the same.

Comment: cls, which Cython version are you using? Which piece of documentation your code is based upon?

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Cython version 0.19.1. Example ist based on http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a C++ object in a python function that is allowed to return python objects only:

```
def clone(self):
    return self.thisptr.clone()
```

Make it this:

```
cdef _Object clone(self) except *:
    return self.thisptr.clone()
```

But it depends on what you're trying to do, you probably want to return Object and not _Object, so I would modify it this way:

```
cdef class Object:
    cdef _Object thisobj
    cdef _Object *thisptr    

    def __cinit__(self, Object obj=None):
        if obj:
            self.thisobj = obj.thisobj.clone()
        self.thisptr = &self.thisobj

    def __dealloc__(self):
        pass

    def clone(self):
        return Object(self)
```

Comment: Correct, I want to return `Object`, not `_Object`

Comment: I thought this could work as a general solution, not just in the special case of this example where a clone method exists: `def __cinit__(self, _Object obj=None): ...` But `__cinit__` does not accept an `_Object` because it cannot convert it to a Python object.

Comment: @cls You cannot pass C++ objects to constructors, this is not allowed, but you can can set the property after the object is constructed. `obj = Object(); obj.thisptr = myCppObj;`. You could create wrapper functions for this: `cdef CreateObject(_Object _obj): obj = Object(); obj.thisptr = _obj; return obj;`.

Comment: To make @Czarek's solution work, you need to modify the C++ clone method to return a pointer:
 
    class Object {
     public:
        Object* clone() {
            Object *p;
            p = new Object();
            return p; 
        }
    };

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Possible, but that seems awkward: Each class needs a wrapper function and a constructor which does not set the thisptr in order to be usable as a return type.

Comment: @cls Cython is not perfect (hence the 0.19.1 number), but very usable.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak You are assigning an `_Object` to `obj.thisptr` which  is of type `_Object*`, so your `CreateObject` function would not compile. Simply addding a `&` to create a pointer does not seem to work. `cdef _Object* test = &_Object()` results in a `Taking address of non-lvalue` compiler error.

Comment: @cls Make it `cdef _Object* test = new _Object()`.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Okay, but the problem arises again with `self.thisptr = obj.thisptr.clone()` in your answer. `clone` returns a value, not a pointer. In general: If the C++ method creates an object and returns it by value, how can I assign it to the `thisptr` of the wrapper?

Comment: Is it too much to ask that the code in an answer compiles before I accept it?