# C++ pointers in Cython

Tags: python, c++, c++11, pointers, cython

I use Cython to wrap my C++ classes. Some of methods return sth. like `class_name*`. `class_name` may be some complicated class already described in pxd and pyx file (like it is mentioned here in extended answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116733/4881441). But Cython says in pyx defs that I am returning not a Python type. I want to be able to return c++-like pointers in python and then use methods of this objects and to pass them to c++ methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return new C++ objects in Cython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882625/how-to-return-new-c-objects-in-cython)

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly return a pointer from a `def` method (only from a `cdef`).

You'll need to write a Cython Wrapper class that stores the pointer you want to pass and you can return this Wrapper Object.
If you want to execute methods on the C++ object you also have to use your Cython Wrapper and delegate the method calls to the stored instance.